# Bash Scripting on Ubuntu - write a log entry when idle time exceeds 5 minutes

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I'm working on an Ubuntu computer and I want to write a script that will send a date and time and idle time to a log file whenever the computer is idle on the GUI console for more than 5 minutes.

I've found that xprintidle will do the monitoring for me but I don't know how to write the script to watch for it to get to 5 minutes and then output to the log.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
while true; do
    idle=$(xprintidle)
    if [[ $idle -gt 300000 ]]; then
        # more than 5 minutes (in milliseconds)
        date "+%F %T $idle" >> $HOME/idle.log
    fi
    sleep 300
done
```

Comment: That looks like it will work just fine. I'll try it out Monday. Thanks!

Comment: Works great. Thanks a bunch!